# How to test a gatsby page containing components with multiple static queries?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, gatsby

I'm looking into tests for my Gatsby site where I have a home page component. Which renders the layout and the homepage content itself. The layout on it's own renders the footer and header.

The layout uses a static query for the site name, and the footer and header use static queries for the footer content and header menu structure.

Currently I am only able to mock one of the static queries as you can see in the example below. How am I able to mock all these three static queries? And what is best practice/nicest way for mocking all these three static queries?

My current test looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import { useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

import Homepage from "../src/pages/index"

beforeEach(() => {
    useStaticQuery.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      "site": {
        "siteMetadata": {
          "title": "Test title"
        }
      }
    }))
})  


describe("Homepage", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    const data = {
      "homePageData": {
        "edges": [{
          "node": {
            "frontmatter": {
              "title": "This is the title",
              "description": "Test description",
              "techstack": [{"label": "C#"}],
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }

    const tree = renderer
      .create(<Homepage data={data}/>)
      .toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

This succesfully mocks the layout static query. But fails on the footer and header static queries because they aren't mocked. With the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'footerData' of undefined
```

My layout component looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Header from "./header"
import Footer from "./footer"
import "../../styles/main.scss"

const Layout = ({ children, hideSearchBar = false, sectionClass = "" }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} hideSearchBar={hideSearchBar} />
      <section className={`section ${sectionClass}`}>
        {children}
      </section>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

My footer looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export default () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query FooterContentQuery {
            footerData: allMarkdownRemark(filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "footer" } } }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        frontmatter {
                            text
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)
    const { frontmatter: footer } = data.footerData.edges[0].node

    return (
        <footer>
            <div className="container has-text-centered">
                <hr/>
                <p>
                    Copyright © {new Date().getFullYear()} - <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: footer.text }} />
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you able to add the layout component that you are testing?

Comment: Like mocking the layout component? Or what do you mean by adding the layout component? Mocking the layout component seems like a good solution but no clue how I can mock it.

Comment: Sorry. I mean are you able to add the component to the question?

Comment: Oh yes of course. I added the layout and footer components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I tried something myself and came to the following solution:

It mocks all the static queries and returns data for the layout, footer and header. I think this is not the nicest solution. So if anyone knows a better solution let me know!

```
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import { useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

import Homepage from "../src/pages/index"

beforeEach(() => {
    useStaticQuery.mockImplementation(() => ({
      "site": {
        "siteMetadata": {
          "title": "Test title"
        }
      },
      "footerData": {
        "edges": [{
            "node": {
                "frontmatter": {
                    "text": "This is the footer" 
                }
            }
        }]
      },
      "navbarData": {
        "edges": [{
            "node": {
                "frontmatter": {
                    "menuItems": [{"label": "Home","linkURL": "/"},]
                }
            }
        }]
      }
    }))
})  


describe("Homepage", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    const data = {
      "homePageData": {
        "edges": [{
          "node": {
            "frontmatter": {
              "title": "This is the title",
              "description": "Test description",
              "techstack": [{"label": "C#"}],
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }

    const tree = renderer
      .create(<Homepage data={data}/>)
      .toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Comment: This saved me! It's good to note that Gatsby's docs use StaticQuery rather than the useStaticQuery hook to mock the data before running the test. And I'm not sure why, but that doesn't seem to create the right thing before the test runs. I kept getting a "cannot read property of undefined" error, and switching to the useStaticQuery hook seemed to work just fine.